# Nodejs - TypeError: 'Y' is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

**Tutorial.js**

```
var exports = module.exports={};
exports.tutorial = function(){
    console.log("11");
}
```

**NodeTutorial.js**

```
var Tutor = require('./Tutorial.js');
module.exports.NodeTutorial = function(){
    console.log("22")   
    function func_pTutor(){
        var PTutor = Tutor;
        PTutor.tutorial();
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
var localTutor = require('./NodeTutorial.js');
localTutor.NodeTutorial();
localTutor.NodeTutorial.func_pTutor();
```

When I run `node app.js`,
I expect my output to be

```
22
11
```

But It throws some error. 
It says 
*TypeError: localTutor.NodeTutorial.func_pTutor is not a function*

Since we have extended our `Tutorial.js` module and exposed a function called `func_pTutor`. It is expected to call the tutorial module.

Please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the line

```
localTutor.NodeTutorial();
```

you *attempt* to create an `NodeTutorial` object, but first of all it you don't since you miss the `new` keyword, and secondly you don't save the object so it is discarded.

Then the next line

```
localTutor.NodeTutorial.func_pTutor();
```

you try to use the object constructor function as an object.

Instead do e.g.

```
var tut = new localTutor.NodeTutorial();  // Create and save object
tut.func_pTutor();  // Call function on object
```

You also need to "export" the function, which is done by making it part of `this`.

For example by doing e.g.

```
this.func_pTutor = function() { ... }
```

Comment: It says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'func_pTutor' of undefined`

Comment: ... and your third line is wrong ("you create an NodeTutorial object") - it doesnt create an object because there is no `new` keyword. (Sorry to nitpick!)